# Rails rename the ID column in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm currently looking at migrating an existing system (written in spaghetti PHP) over to rails. The problem is, it has to run off of a live database. A lot of the ID columns on these different tables aren't named `id`. For instance, the customers table has an ID column called `Customer_ID`. Upon looking, I just realised that rails does infact seem to find by the primary key instead of a specific column called `id`.

Will I face a lot of problems later with the naming of these ID columns, specifically in stuff like relationships?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After v2.3.8, `set_primary_key :col_name` is deprecated.

`self.primary_key = 'col_name'` is recommended.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 2):

Change primary key attribute in model by using

`set_primary_key :col_name`